# requiring the presence of static methods in C#

Tags: c#, generics, static, methods, constraints

Given a group of objects that have a common set of properties and methods in support of given domain logic, is there a way of enforcing the presence of certain static methods on these objects?

I have concluded that implementing an interface does not achieve this (methods are instance only) and that static methods can not be marked override, virtual or abstract.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

(Note: In F# you can express such constraints using "inline" functions and "^" types (e.g. forall types T where T has a static method ToInt(T) that returns an 'int').  The compiler effectively auto-expands each call site to the specific type.)

Answer (score 3):

The only way to force a type to have a static member is to inherit from it. All types will have the static members, and if you need to override them on a derived type you can use the "new" keyword:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Base.Hello());
    Console.WriteLine(Derived.Hello());
    Console.Read();
    /* output will be:
    Hello
    World
    */
}

public class Base
{
    public static object Hello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public static new object Hello()
    {
        return "World";
    }
}
```

It's not quite the same as abstract/override, but from a consumer standpoint, works similarly.